# Отладка приложения - количество памяти

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Как узнать сколько памяти потребляет приложение (на С#) при работе? Либо "участок кода" - допустим есть метод который считывает данные, можно ли узнать сколько памяти он потребляет во время работы.

```
ds.ReadXml(xml);
```

IDE - VS2012

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под физической памятью?

Comment: Может что то кэшируется на жесткий диск

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Отслеживание изменений в оперативной памяти:

1. С помощью кода:

   ```
   long before = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
   // ваш код тут
   long after = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
   int consumedInMegabytes = (after - before) / (1024 * 1024);
   ```

   Опционально может потребоваться собрать мусор до и/или после
   тестируемого кода (параметр `GetTotalMemory` поставить в `true`).
2. С помощью профайлеров (суть аналогична): снять снэпшот до
   тестируемого кода, выполнить код, снять снэпшот после, сравнить два
   снэпшота. Профайлер поможет ответить не только на на вопрос
   "сколько?", но и "на что?".

Comment: Ни одна из перегрузок метода не принимает 0 аргументов. Так что надо указывать аргументы - true/false (дождаться сборки мусора или нет).

Comment: Пардон, исправил.